# Where to place SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS against the DISTINCT keyword?

Tags: mysql

I cannot get the result returned by `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` so I post the thread : where is the correct position to place SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS against the DISTINCT keyword , example `SELECT DISTINCT myColumn FROM myTable WHERE someConditions;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is this:

> ```
> SELECT
>     [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
>       [HIGH_PRIORITY]
>       [MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = N]
>       [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
>       [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
>       [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
>     select_expr [, select_expr ...]
> ```
>
> [...]

In practice, order does not seem to matter as long as you respect the overall syntax (e.g., don't put `WHERE` before `FROM`):

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS COUNT(*) FROM emails;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM emails;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```